# Transparent section header?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, uitableviewsectionheader

I'm creating a transparent `List` with transparent rows and section headers.

But as soon as the rows slide under the section header, it **automatically features a background blur**. I understand the sentiment, but would like to opt out.

[image]

Did anyone manage to hide it somehow? Leaving the section header background entirely transparent?

```
struct HeaderView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("Map")
                .opacity(0.5)
            List {
                Section(
                    header: VStack {
                        Text("Section 1")
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                            .frame(height: 60)
                    },
                    content: {
                        ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { eachRowIndex in
                            Text("Row \(eachRowIndex)")
                                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .padding(.top, 40)
        }
    }
}
```

Preferably iOS 13 SwiftUI, but I'm curious if there is anything to do with it in UIKit as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add empty view to `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`

```
struct HeaderView: View {
    init() {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().backgroundView = UIView() // here
    }

// Other code
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I tried setting `backgroundView` to `nil` already, but that did not work out.

Comment: doesn't work anymore

Comment: When creating the ```HeaderView``` just add a ```backgroundView```. I set the ```backgroundColor``` of the ```backgroundView``` to be ```UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.4)``` That way you can see the header and also see through it.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 13, I needed to introspect [`UITableViewHeaderFooterView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewheaderfooterview), and set `backgroundView` manually there (which needs an [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) extension as well).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().backgroundView = UIView()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(
                header: HStack {
                    ...
                }
                .introspectTableViewHeaderFooterView {
                    $0.backgroundView = UIView()
                },
                
                content: {
                    ForEach { 
                        ...
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

```
extension View {
    
    public func introspectTableViewHeaderFooterView(customize: @escaping (UITableViewHeaderFooterView) -> Void) -> some View {
        introspect(selector: TargetViewSelector.ancestorOrSiblingContaining, customize: customize)
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work anymore